# What's the right way to ensure jms consumers are closed using spring integration?

Tags: java, jms, spring-integration

I'm using spring integration to invoke a service on the other end of an active mq. My config looks like:

```
<bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
                  p:brokerURL="${risk.approval.queue.broker}"
                  p:userName="${risk.approval.queue.username}"
                  p:password="${risk.approval.queue.password}"
                    />
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true"/>
        <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="100"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- create and close a connection to prepopulate the pool -->
    <bean factory-bean="jmsConnectionFactory" factory-method="createConnection" class="javax.jms.Connection"
          init-method="close" />

    <integration:channel id="riskApprovalRequestChannel"/>
    <integration:channel id="riskApprovalResponseChannel"/>

    <jms:outbound-gateway id="riskApprovalServiceGateway"
                          request-destination-name="${risk.approval.queue.request}"
                          reply-destination-name="${risk.approval.queue.response}"
                          request-channel="riskApprovalRequestChannel"
                          reply-channel="riskApprovalResponseChannel"
                          connection-factory="jmsConnectionFactory"
                          receive-timeout="5000"/>

    <integration:gateway id="riskApprovalService" service-interface="com.my.super.ServiceInterface"
                         default-request-channel="riskApprovalRequestChannel"
                         default-reply-channel="riskApprovalResponseChannel"/>
```

What I've noticed is that with this config the consumers created to grab the matching request from active mq never close. Every request increments the consumer count.

I can stop this from happening by adding

```
<property name="cacheConsumers" value="false" />
```

To the CachingConnectionFactory.

However according to the java docs for CachingConnectionFactory :

> Note that durable subscribers will only be cached until logical
>   closing of the Session handle.

Which suggests that the session is never being closed.

Is this a bad thing? Is there a better way to stop the consumers from piling up?

Cheers,
Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you don't need the init-method on your factory-bean - it does nothing - the session factory only has one connection and calling close() on it is a no-op. (CCF is a subclass of SingleConnectionFactory).

Second; caching consumers is the default; sessions are never closed, unless the number of sessions exceeds the sessionCacheSize (which you have set to 100).

When close() is called on a cached session, it is cached for reuse; that's what the caching connection factory is **for** - avoiding the overhead of session creation for every request.

If you don't want the performance benefit of caching sessions, producers and consumers, use the SingleConnectionFactory instead. See the JavaDoc for CachingConnectionFactory.

Comment: Thanks for some good info. The reasoning for closing the consumers is that they all have correlation id selectors, so they'll never be candidates for reuse. Given that I have no other consumers I think I'll switch to SingleConnectionFactory as you have suggested.

Comment: However, then you will lose caching of sessions and producers too. You were actually doing the right thing before - using a caching connection factory with cacheConsumers=false. That way, you get the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work when using `cachingConnectionFactory`?

In your spring config file add in the connection factory config details something like this: `cacheConsumers="false"`

Default Behaviour is *true* which was causing a connection leak in the Queue.